# SSRS Repeat Page Header for a Matrix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I am sure this has been asked a million times, but the answers say set either the marix's "Repeat header rows on each page" or set the static members KeepWithGroup property and RepeatOnNewPage.

But it is not working.

In my scenario a Matrix I have a single group but multiple detail columns (i.e. I deleted the groups all except the first one, if that makes a difference! I also have 2 levels of Column Groups.

If I select the group I have FixedData and KeepToGether properties, setting either to True does nothing. I then have 10 static columns under my group in Advance mode and I have also tried setting the properties FixedData, KeepTogether, KeepWithGroup and RepeatOnNewPage for the top one, bottom one and all of them and nothing seems to work neither repeat header on each page nor fixed header when scrolling. What does it mean where I have read set on adjacent columns as required. If one column in the header row is repeated then surely all of them have to be repeated because they are on the same row, therefore it should be only one setting I have to make not multiple. I have never had a problem with a Table with these settings just a Matrix.

Answer (score 0):

I have figure it out you are suppose to select matrix's "Repeat header columns on each page (or keep header visible while scrolling" not header rows. Just my misinterpretation.